# Can a dummy variable only take the values 1 or 0

Tags: regression, categorical-data, binary-data

Is it possible for dummy variables in a regression model to take on any value. I added a variable to my model with two variables (one dependent and one independent) and called it a dummy variable that can take on any Integer value > 0. This value also give me some information about my observations. But i was told i cannot call it a dummy variable as it is does not take on a binary value.

I did read some articles and got some definitions, but i can't seem to find an example of a dummy variable that can take on any value. I just want to confirm that a dummy variable can only be binary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is gender typically coded 0/1 rather than 1/2, for example?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16689/why-is-gender-typically-coded-0-1-rather-than-1-2-for-example) see also http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203993/why-0-for-failure-and-1-for-success-in-a-bernoulli-distribution/204007#204007

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, a dummy variable can take values either 1 or 0. It can express either a binary variable (for instance, man/woman, and it's on you to decide which gender you encode to be 1 and which to be 0), or a categorical variables (for instance, level of education: basic/college/postgraduate).

In the case of categorical data, you need one dummy (binary) variable for each category: basic=1 if the person has only completed basic education, 0 otherwise, college=1 if the person has only completed college education, 0 otherwise; postgraduate=1 if the person has completed postgraduate education, 0 otherwise. Then, because they are perfectly multicollinear (knowing the value of two of the variables for an individual uniquely determines the third of them - for instance, an individual with neither college nor postgraduate sure has basic education), you drop one of them in the regression, that will serve as the base category.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the most common kind of dummy variables is as you described: A binary variable that can only take on 0 or 1. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics))

My statistics professor used to call a variable with effect coding (-1,0,1) a dummy variable, but he is the only one I know, who did that.

What you have created is a categorical variable. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable)
What you can do, is break down the categorical variable into single dummy variables, where one category is indicated by one dummy variable.