# How to convert binary category feature to numeric feature, like 'Gender'?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

In a machine learning or data mining problem, suppose I have a original feature named "Gender", and now I want to convert this feature to numeric feature, there are two ways to do that, but I realy do not know which one is better?

1. Convert to one feature, and 1 represented 'male' and 0 represented 'female'
2. Convert to two diffent feature, just like one-hot encoding, like 'ismale' and other one is 'isfemale'

thx

Answer (score 6):

The second coding brings absolutely no information, since `ismale` is perfectly correlated to `isfemale` and always if first is true, then the second must be false. So introducing the second variable does nothing. In general, to encode $k$ categories, you need $k-1$ dummy variables, since if each of the $k-1$ dummies it false, then $k$'th "default" category must be true (assuming that your data represents something like single-choice questions, so the categories are exclusive and exactly one needs to be true).

See also related threads
[Why is gender typically coded 0/1 rather than 1/2, for example?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16689/why-is-gender-typically-coded-0-1-rather-than-1-2-for-example)
[Why 0 for failure and 1 for success in a Bernoulli distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203993/why-0-for-failure-and-1-for-success-in-a-bernoulli-distribution/204007#204007)

You may also be interested in reading the [What is a contrast matrix (a term, pertaining to an analysis with categorical predictors)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/78354/35989) thread.

Comment: This might depend on the classifier, though, at least for for $k$ categories. For example, if you used feature selection, and the $k$th feature is needed, your feature selection algorithm would have to keep all $k-1$ features.